# How do you crop a symbol in illustrator without changing every symbol?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols, crop

Is there a way to crop a symbol on your artboard without altering the other symbols on the artboard that are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Add a **clipping mask** to the symbol instance on the artboard.

- Draw a path around what you *want* to show.
- Place the path above the symbol instance
- Select both
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

> [image]

This does *not* change the symbol in *any* way. 
It merely hides part of that particular symbol instance.